# regex with two main group. Two sub-group in one the main group. Where same group level order does not count

Tags: regex, set

I try to to write a regex that should be as follow. (I use a custom notation)

```
{{x|X|m|M|t|T|a|i|W|w}, {J|<null>}}, {integer+}
```

where:

- `|` means XOR
- `{}` curly braces means it is a set: the order has no importance
- letters are CASE-SENSITIVE

**Question: how to write such a regex?**

Let me try to explain what I want to achieve by analyzing the custom notation, piece by piece:

**Analysis of the query piece by piece**

`{x|X|m|M|t|T|a|i|W|w}` means the regex should detect ONE AND ONLY ONE  character in the

`{J|<null>}` means that the regex should detect ONE AND ONLY ONE of the elements in the set.

`{{x|X|m|M|t|T|a|i|W|w},{J|<null>}}`  means **for instance** that the regex should detect the following

- `xJ`
- `Jx` [because the order does not matter between the two sub-sets inside the big.
- `M<null>`

`{{x|X|m|M|t|T|a|i|W|w},{J|<null>}}` means **for instance** that the regex should **NOT** detect the following

- `xJaslk`
- `xX`  [because the regex must detect only and only 1 element in each set]

`{integer+}` means any INTEGER bigger than 0 [i.e. starting from 1 to infinite]. For instance 3 or 342 or 333 should be detected. However 2.0 or 3,4 should not be detected. Ideally 1.0 or 1,0 should be equal to 1 but if it is not possible let's skip that because the regex is already complex in my opinion.

**Analysis of the query in its entire form**

So If I put `{{x|X|m|M|t|T|a|i|W|w}, {J|<null>}}, {integer+}`  together here are some **legal examples**

- `W33`
- `Jx848`
- `848a`
- `848Jx`
- `848xJ`
- `xJ848`
- `Jx848`

And the following examples are **illegal examples**

- `848.34Ja`
- `W33,33`
- `848a848`
- `W33W`
- `x848J`

PS: Just in case, I try to use that regex in Java.

**Question: how to write such a regex?**

Comment: Doesn't your initial expression *require* a `{integer+}` at the end?  It does not appear inside a `{}`.

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes it does require a {integer+} at the end.

Comment: What is this *`|` means XOR*?

Comment: @revo yes it means XOR [I may update the symbol in case there is a more appropriate symbol... Just tell me if you have a suggestion]

Comment: If `{integer+}` is required on the end, then `848Jx` is not a legal example.

Answer (score 0):

My instinct is that you should not try to write one big regex, though it is possible. Your three pieces break down into:

- `x|X|m|M|t|T|a|i|W|w`
- `J?`
- `[1-9]\d*`

And you want to optionally match each of them in any order. In this case, there are 6 possible permutations:

- `(x|X|m|M|t|T|a|i|W|w)?(J?)?([1-9]\d*)?`
- `(J?)?(x|X|m|M|t|T|a|i|W|w)?([1-9]\d*)?`
- etc

(Note that `(J?)?` is equivalent to `J?`.) You could then `or` all of these together: `(<first case>)|(<second case>)|...|(<sixth case>)`, but it's going to be error prone. I would iterate over the permutations of the groups, interpolate into a string and test each case individually.

Answer (score 0):

At this point I created the following regex :

```
(?|([XmMtTaiWw])|(Jx|xJ)|([1-9][0-9]*))+(?!\1)
```

So far so good, but it takes the `848a848` and `W33W`. I didn't manage to ignore duplicates groups in a simple way. In fact, the regex is already too complicated in my opinion.

You can try it here : [Clic here to go to Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)